# serve a static file in nginx based on domain extension.ltd?

Tags: nginx, domain, regex

I was wondering and already did some extensive searches on how to serve a static file based on the domain.LTD extension.

Nginx.conf:

```
error_page 502 /maintenance.html; 
location = /maintenance.html { root /srv/books/current/app/views/layouts/; }
```

What I want is to serve a localised maintenance page based on the extension of the domain for that current request. Is this possible somehow using regex or any nginx directives?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like..

```
error_page 502 /maintenance.html; 
location = /maintenance.html {
  if ($http_host ~* "\.([^\.]+)$") {
    set $tld $1;
    rewrite ^ /maint/$tld.html last;
  }
}

location /maint/ {
  root /path/to/somewhere/maint/com.html;
}
```

That should make it load `com.html` for the maint page for `example.com`, etc.

Comment: testing this now, you removed the root variable? how to add that back in. I assume like rewrite ^ /my/root/path/to/maintenance_$tld.html last; to load /my/root/path/to/maintenance_com.html?

Comment: @Rubytastic This would have a different location block handle where the root configuration resides, since nothing but `/maintenance.html` matches this location block.  See edit.